# Python xlWings generate json-File from Range object

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I want to generate a json File from a Python xlWings Range object:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlwings as xw
 wb=xw.Book(file)
 ws=wb.sheets[0]
 dr=ws.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame)
 df=pd.DataFrame(data=dr)

 jfile=df.to_json(orient='columns')
```

at this point the program is in an endless loop:
df=pd.DataFrame(data=dr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.value` on the end of the `dr=` line, then you will set `dr` as a DataFrame, and there will be no need to use the line `df=pd.DataFrame(data=dr)`

`ws.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame)` returns a range object, so trying to turn this into a DataFrame is unlikely to be what you are trying to do.  This was the output from my test data, where the used range was A1:D11:

```py
#Out[]: 
#                                    0
#0    (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$A$1>)))
#1    (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$B$1>)))
#2    (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$C$1>)))
#3    (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$D$1>)))
#4    (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$A$2>)))
#...
#39  (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$D$10>)))
#40  (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$A$11>)))
#41  (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$B$11>)))
#42  (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$C$11>)))
#43  (((<Range [Book1]Sheet1!$D$11>)))
```

If you instead use `ws.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame).value`, then the type of data returns is pd.DataFrame and then then can be converted to json:

```py
df = ws.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame).value
jfile=df.to_json(orient='columns')
```

See the documentation for converters and options here with an example, which uses `.value`, [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#:%7E:text=name%2C%20dtype%3A%20float64-,Pandas%20DataFrame%20converter,-%23).

Returned types:

```py
type(ws.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame))
#Out[]: xlwings.main.Range
type(ws.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame).value)
#Out[]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```